# Splitting names in one cell and adding commas between to new cell

Tags: excel, function

I am an excel novice, and I really have no idea what I am doing...

But I have a list of 1500 names in Column A.  I'd like to have a function for column C that takes each work in Column A and adds a comma between them, and displays that in Column C...

I have the names in Column A, and want to create a string of tags that will be in Column C.

Also, if it's possible to get the first letter of the last word in the string, then Column C will be made up of First Name, Last Name, First Letter of Last Name.

Any help would be great!

SAMPLE

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a sample of names in Col A and also a sample output?

Comment: What happens if you have names like `Jon Bon Jovi`?

Comment: I actually only have 10 of those names out of the 1500, and I can set those manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your pick :)

If you use this formula in Cell B1 and copy it down

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ")&", "&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),1)`

then you will get the output as shown in Col B

And if you use this formula in cell C1 and copy it down

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & ", "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),"")&", "&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),1)`

then your output will be like Col C

[image]

**EDIT**

**3rd Scenario**

Put this in Cell D1 and copy it down.

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),""))&", "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))&", "&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),1)`

Output in Col D

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you want output like `Jon Bon, Jovi, J`. That can also be achieved.

Comment: Oh I love you.  This is perfect.  I was close with the code I had sorta come up with. What would be the best way to span this function all the way down the C Column?  Just select all those cells?

Comment: Updated my post with the 3rd scenario. :) You can use the Excel's Autofill feature to copy formulas down.